# How can i use any dataset form SQL in GoogleChart?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gchart

How can i use any dataset form SQL in GoogleChart? i really like googleChart. But i want to use Gchart with  dataset from Sql' query result in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Google charts take a formatted string for the data feed as I'm sure you know.

you will need to loop through your dataset and generate this string then write it out to the page in a Literal control.

For example

```
DataSet d = GetDataSet();// returns your data
string percentages = string.Empty;
string names = string.Empty;
string baseUrl = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=250x100";

foreach(DataRow row in d.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    string tName = row["name"].ToString();
    int value = (int)row["value"];
    names += name + "|";
    percentages += value.ToString() + ",";
}

names = names.TrimEnd('|');
percentages = percentages.TrimEnd(',');

string fullUrl = baseUrl + "&chd=t:" + percentages;
fullUrl += "&chl=" + namesl


image1.ImageUrl = fullUrl;
```